# htaccess RewriteRule redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, centos, panel

I have an issue with new installed centos web panel where I am using below htaccess code to redirect to index.php if file not exists where if estate.php exists then it goes directly to estate.php and if i use estate without .php then it goes to index.php.

This code below works anywhere but not on CWP (centos web panel) and the problem is that it still works for the files that don't exist at all but if file estate.php exist and in url i use estate without .php it goes to esate.php and ignors to go to index.php.

so the question is that is there any way to force it to go to index.php even if file exists but if i use estate.php then it should go directly to estate.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the Multiviews

Try adding the following line in your htaccess above RewriteEngine  directive :

```
Options -Multiviews
```